# DataTables.net fnServerParams change of parameter

Tags: datatables

If I update some parameters in fnServerParams(), they are not taken into account by the DataTables presentation layer, any idea?

E.g. let's assume iDisplayStart=10 and iDisplayEnd=20 are correct values

```
'fnServerParams': function (aoData) {
    // Find i such as aoData[i]['name'] == 'iDisplayStart'
    aoData[i]['value'] = 10;
    // Find j such as aoData[j]['name'] == 'iDisplayEnd'
    aoData[j]['value'] = 20;
},
```

Then the paging button is still stuck on page 1 while I expect it to show page 2 of my data.
The same for sorting parameters.

Edit: The initialization code is as follows:

```
var oTable = $('#WEB_TABLE_ID').dataTable(
                       {'aaSorting': [[0, 'desc']],
                        'bProcessing': true,
                        'bServerSide': true,
                        'sAjaxSource': '../subscription/search_list.php',
                        'sServerMethod': 'POST',
                        'sPaginationType': 'full_numbers',
                        'iDisplayLength': 100,  // Default number of rows to display
                        'oLanguage': {'sSearch': "Search all",
                        'sLengthMenu': 'Display <select>   \
<option value="10">10</option>                             \
<option value="100">100</option>                           \
<option value="500">500</option>                           \
</select> entries',},
                        'bAutoWidth': false,
                        'sDom': "<'row'<'span8'l><'top'i>r>t<'row'<'bottom'i><'span8'p>>"
                        'fnServerParams': function (aoData) {
                            var sEcho = aoData[0].value;
                            if ('1' == sEcho) {
                                var params = <?=json_encode(Session::read(${CTL_DATAID}))?>;
                                if (! $.isEmptyObject(params)) {
                                    aoData.length = 0; // empty array
                                    $.each(params, function(name, value) {
                                        aoData.push({'name': name, 'value': value});
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                        },
);
```

Comment: Can you paste the code where you initialize datatables?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a direct solution to my question, but as it was to save the state of the DataTable, I came accross the bStateSave option that does the job.